# I have an angular application that works fine on IE9 and above, but it fails to do so on IE8

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-8

I have an angular application that works fine on IE9 and above, but it fails to do so on IE8.

When the application is served it brings black page on IE8.

I have imported all the required modules in polyfill.ts file, but it still doesn't work on IE8. Is there a work around on this issue or is it a dead end.

This is my polyfill.ts file

```
     /**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';


/**
 * Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`
 * Only required if AnimationBuilder is used within the application and using IE/Edge or Safari.
 * Standard animation support in Angular DOES NOT require any polyfills (as of Angular 6.0).
 **/
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.

/**
 * By default, zone.js will patch all possible macroTask and DomEvents
 * user can disable parts of macroTask/DomEvents patch by setting following flags
 */

 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_requestAnimationFrame = true; // disable patch requestAnimationFrame
 // (window as any).__Zone_disable_on_property = true; // disable patch onProperty such as onclick
 // (window as any).__zone_symbol__BLACK_LISTED_EVENTS = ['scroll', 'mousemove']; // disable patch specified eventNames

 /*
 * in IE/Edge developer tools, the addEventListener will also be wrapped by zone.js
 * with the following flag, it will bypass `zone.js` patch for IE/Edge
 */
// (window as any).__Zone_enable_cross_context_check = true;

/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * APPLICATION IMPORTS
 */
```

These are some of the details of my application.

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.4
Node: 8.12.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version

@angular-devkit/architect    0.8.4
@angular-devkit/core         0.8.4
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.8.4
@schematics/angular          0.8.4
@schematics/update           0.8.4
rxjs                         6.2.2
typescript                   2.9.2
```

Comment: Angular doesn't support IE8, per https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: IE 8 is too old and outdated version and it is recommended to upgrade to IE 11 version. IE 11 is the only version which currently has product support.